# Electric interference from cnc spindle

Tags: motor, electronics

I've got a CNC machine and I recently started using a spindle for it. At first it was running smoothly with no issues, but after the first brush pair wore off (I've replaced them later on) it started interfering with the Arduino/gshield and pc monitor. The monitor displays a "no signal" message, although after turning off the spindle or turning it to a low speed the signal comes back. The other problem is that after running a long job, sometimes the gshield disconnects and the job stops midway.

- What part could be causing all this interference?
- How can I shield that part so it stops interfering with other electronics?

I am using the following hardware:

- 600 watt spindle
- 600 watt power supply with variable speed
- the wires from the spindle to the power supply are not shielded, although Ive tried covering them with aluminium foil, not sure if that should be of any benefit, I've read it somewhere so I gave it a try.
- Gshield with Arduino, connected to a Raspberry pi.

All the electronics are within 70 cm radius.

Comment: What part could be causing all this interference? If the interference started when you replaced the brushes then suspect the brushes are causing arcing and so generating interference. Try some better quality ones.

Comment: *"At first it was running smoothly with no issues..."*, which is good, but then *"the first brush pair wore off"* and *"I've replaced them"*. I would suggest that you stop focusing on the country that manufactured the spindle and look instead on what changed to make the problem occur.

Comment: Brushes often need to "wear in" so that the ends of them fit nicely to the curvature of the commutator. Until that point you can get a lot more sparking than normal.

Comment: if the X  part dicsonnects, there probaly is arcing and making interference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would guess that arcing in the spindle causes spikes that travel through the power supplies and power wires. One thing you could try is to use a really long extension cord (say 15 meters or more) to power the spindle power supply. You can insert this cord to a different power outlet to gain additional distance.

Comment: @Omar K : It might be useful for others encountering similar issues if you described what you did and what results you got. That's what is great about stackexchange / stackoverflow: a huge knowledge base is created, piece by piece.